# Book series about a group of humans who colonise another planet after the Earth is destroyed by the Sun going nova

Tags: story-identification, books, dystopia, space-colonization

Trying to find a series - two books from memory - in which the Earth was destroyed by the Sun going nova. A smallish group fled to a science base to make it a colony. The world was not really suitable - low metals, no rigid building materials, the colonists knelt to hoe fields for example.

The setting is after some time after the nova. Religion is used to stabilise the society and the priests were scientists searching for a way to synthesize metals.

The first book recounts the winning over of a heretic to become a priest mathematician. The second recounts the angst of this priest/scientist when the mathematical approach fails. He eventually comes to terms of the place of faith with science.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which range of years did you read these books, and when do you think they might've been published?

Comment: If anyone correctly identifies this series, you can mark their answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe this is the series [*Children of the Star*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?4853) by [Sylvia Louise Engdahl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvia_Engdahl). The first book was [*This Star Shall Abide*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-title.cgi?9317) (1972). The second is [*Beyond the Tomorrow Mountains*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?9318) (1973). The third is [*The Doors of the Universe*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?9319) (1981)

The [page about the series](http://www.sylviaengdahl.com/cots.htm) on the author's website has this summery:

> Noren knew that his world was not as it should be--it was wrong that only the Scholars, and their representatives the Technicians, could use metal tools and Machines. It was wrong that only they had access to the mysterious City, which he had always longed to enter. Above all, it was wrong for the Scholars to have sole power over the distribution of knowledge. The High Law imposed these restrictions and many others, though the Prophecy promised that someday knowledge and Machines would be available to everyone. Noren was a heretic. He defied the High Law and had no faith in the Prophecy's fulfillment. But the more he learned of the grim truth about his people's deprivations, the less possible it seemed that their world could ever be changed. It would take more drastic steps than anyone imagined to restore their rightful heritage.

**Matches**:

The colonists fled a nova about to destroy the solar system where their species had evolved.  They had only recently developed star travel, and had no out-systems colonies, only a small science base whose personnel were expecting only a short tour of duty. The group able to flee is small, smaller than the people on the base to which they travel. The planet has no accessible metal. The ships carry only a small amount, not enough for an expanding population. The scientists on the escape fleet hope to synthesize metal through fusion, but their science is not yet up to doing so, they do have hydrogen fusion to generate power. Thus the colonists must life in an effectively stone-age environment, with no metal tools. Hoes are stone tied to wooden poles.

The planet's water is contaminated, and must be purified using a machine. Drinking unpurified water leads to genetic damage which reduces descendants to a sub-human level of intelligence. Land must also be decontaminated before it is used to raise crops for human food.

Those who fled the nova announce themselves as a priesthood, and forcibly remove the base personnel from the high-tech settlement.

All the above has occurred many generations before the setting of the novels. All three books have as main character Noren, who is born as a villager (peasant). He insists that it is wrong for the Scholars (priests) to exclude all others from knowledge, that learning should be free to all. He leaves his village, but is eventually caught by the scholars, and believes that he will be tortured and killed for his heresy. But instead he is educated by the scholars, being shown the origin of the system.

> It turns out that only those willing to defy the system dn insist on their right to knowledge are held worthy to be the next generation of Scholars. Noren joins them hoping to help work toward synthesis of metal.

The second book describes a crisis of faith on the part of Noren, when the attempt to develop high-order fusion is proven theoretically impossible.

**Mismatch**: The colonists did not come from Earth, nor our solar system. They refer to their home system as 'Thew Six Worlds" and it is made clear that none of these are Earth. But they seem n many ways earth-like, and we do not get a detailed description of the Six Worlds nor of their culture.

**Excerpt from the first book**:

> As the night waned, Noren wandered aimlessly; though his knee throbbed painfully under the bandage, he was able to limp, and some inner urge would not allow him to keep still. It was not merely an urge to evade capture. Rather, he was irresistibly drawn to a place where the great towers, the central one topped with its blazing beacon, were in full view.
>
> Dawn found him back at the plaza. In front of him the City walls thrust up, solid and forbidding against the pale morning sky. He noticed that their surface was not straight, but curved, and wondered why they had been built that way. There were so many inexplicable things about the City, so many things that he longed desperately to understand. . . .
>
> At the lowest corner of the broad flight of steps leading to the Gates, he slumped wearily. What next? Arrest was imminent; he could neither buy food nor, because of his bad knee, could he work for it; and what hope was there of achieving anything if the only people who recognized the High Law's fallacies wanted either to destroy all that was good in the world or to set themselves up in the Scholars' place?
>
> An aircar, sunlight catching its rotors, hovered briefly and dropped out of sight behind the high barrier. On either side of the steps, produce was being loaded into boxlike caverns in the walls; several Technicians were supervising. Noren eyed them nervously, then turned his back and sat on the bottom step, looking out toward the market stalls that lined the opposite side of the square. A crowd of people was again gathering. All at once music, loud and heart-stirring, burst from somewhere behind the Gates and reverberated through the plaza. It swelled in volume until Noren felt as if he might burst also; it was like nothing he had ever heard, and it made him want to sing or to shout or even to cry.
>
> It faded; the crowd hushed. Above him the huge Gates parted and a blue-robed Scholar appeared, flanked by four Technicians. Immediately the people in the plaza fell to their knees.
>
> Startled, Noren remembered too late the Benison that preceded the daily opening of the markets. The Scholar would read from the Book of the Prophecy. He had no desire to stay, but he would only attract attention to himself if he moved, for everyone was waiting, motionless, eyes raised toward the sky in sober respect. Yet he would not kneel! If he was reprimanded, he decided, he could state quite honestly that the injury to his knee made it impossible.
>
> He turned toward the Gates and lifted his eyes with the rest. A trace of breeze fluttered the sleeves of the Scholar's robe as he opened the book. His voice, mysteriously amplified, floated past Noren, on out to the edge of the plaza with undiminished clarity.
>
> "*'Let us rejoice in the bounty of the land! For the land is good, and from the Mother Star came the heritage that has blessed it; the land has given us life--'*"
>
> The knowledge they were hiding could give people a better life, thought Noren bitterly.
>
> "*'Those who have brought forth life from the land are rich--'*"
>
> But not as rich as those who had access to the Power and the Machines.
>
> "*'For through the land's taming shall our strength grow, that we may be ready to receive the ancient knowledge--'*"
>
> No doubt, when the predicted date arrived, people would be told they weren't ready; the Mother Star would hide its face in shame! Noren scowled. He knew the words well and in fact had read the entire book many times, having been taught his letters from it as a child, but he had not spotted that loophole before. Whoever had inserted it had planned carefully.
>
> "*'. . .And the people shall multiply across the face of the earth, and at no time shall the spirit of the Mother Star die in the hearts of its children.'*"

> All the families, Noren reflected--all the good, sincere people who recited those words every time they sat down to eat--they'd been tricked by the Scholars into putting their trust in something false! Talyra trusted it implicitly, and she too was the victim of cold-blooded deception.
>
> Glaring at the High Priest who stood above him, he was abruptly overpowered by the hot anger that had been building up in him for years. He could no longer contain it. What do you believe, Scholar? he raged. What is it that lets you stand up there and exhort people to attach their natural faith in goodness to what you know is a figment of somebody's imagination?
>
> He looked back at the mass of rapt faces. Those people would never turn against the Scholars. There was no conceivable way he could make them listen, nothing he could do that would be even a small step toward changing the world into the sort of place the Prophecy described. And he was almost too weary to care. He almost wished the Technicians would arrest him and get it over with.
>
> The spired towers glistened overhead, dazzling his vision. All mysteries were sealed away there . . . and he had a right to share those mysteries! Yet neither he nor anybody else would ever be granted that right. The idea of its depending on the appearance of a mythical Mother Star was too firmly entrenched. The spirit of this Star shall abide forever--there was a certain degree of truth in that declaration. By the success of their deceits, the Scholars had made it true.
>
> People wouldn't oppose the High Law on being told that the Prophecy wasn't authentic because that would be acting not so much against bad rulers as against their own beliefs. The real trouble, Noren saw suddenly, was that most people had no reason to think the Scholars were bad. As High Priests, they did not interfere with ordinary villagers' lives. Yet if someone were to commit an act of overt defiance, wouldn't they have to interfere? Wouldn't they be forced to silence him immediately, without waiting for the formality of a civil trial?
>
> Noren clenched wet fingers, an idea forming out of his desperation. They were going to kill him sometime. Why not in front of the whole Benison assemblage? Why not in a way that would provide the people who revered them with proof, real proof, of their underlying ruthlessness?
>
> His heart raced. The Scholar was reading the last page of the Prophecy; within seconds after he closed the book, the music might surge up again. There wasn't time to deliberate, Noren rose from the step and moved forward.
>
> "*'. . .through the time of waiting we will follow the Law--'*" As those words were reached he was part way up the flight, above the crowd; heedless of the pain in his knee, Noren found himself climbing without stumbling. He marshaled every bit of strength he could collect, throwing it all into his voice.
>
> "No! We will not follow the High Law; it is evil! It's wrong for a few men to create a Law above village law and keep all the knowledge for themselves!" He glanced upward over his shoulder; the Technicians had left the Gates and were coming down toward him, unhurriedly and without any show of emotion. "There should be Machines for everyone, Power for everyone, and knowledge should be free!"

I remember waiting for years to read the third book, which provides a quite unexpected resolution to the central problem of the series.

**Covers**

| 1972 Antheanum Pb edition | 1973 Gollancz UK edition |
| --- | --- |
| [image: 1972 Antheanum Pb edition] | [image: 1973 UK edition] |

| Meisha Merlin 2000 Trade Pb Ed | 2010 eBook ed |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Meisha Merlin 2000 Trade Pb Ed] | [image: 2010 eBook ed] |

Comment: that sounds like it. I would have read books one and two maybe 40 years ago or more. Many thanks

Comment: All are available as ebooks via the author's site, and I think elsewhere as qwell. Book one is available as a new PB. I have a one-volume edition of all three from Meshia-Merlin. This is out of print, but used copies might be available, or library copies. I personally enjoyed the books quite ma lot, and i recall on rec.arts.sf.written they came up from time to time, generally recalled positively.